# Vim swap message when opening .bash

Tags: vim, bash

When I try to edit `.bash` I get this message:

[image: vim -r /Users/xxxx/.bash]

Maybe I replaced `.bash` to `.bash.swp` accidentally. So I tried to recover files using command `vim -r /Users/xxxxx/.bash`, though those messages came up and I have no idea what to do.

Can someone tell me how I can recover `.bash`?

Comment: What did you do when presented with that screen? What is `.bash` supposed to be exactly?

Comment: Delete all the swap files `\rm .bash.sw*`. if you have recovered.